# What am I doing wrong with my Hard Cider

Tags: cider, vinegar

Ok so I'm trying to make small 1 gallon batches of hard cider. I've already created 2 batches that sucked really bad (vinegary).

I used:

First batch: (pretty obvious why this one sucked)

- white house apple juice
- baking yeast

Second batch:

- Simply Apple as my base its pasteurized with no preservatives
- I used a half packet of champaign yeast.
- 2 cups brown sugar disolved in 2 cups water

Is there a reliable recipe for doing a small 1 gallon batch of cider w/o having to press apples?

Comment: What are you using to sanitize your equipment?

Comment: Does it taste and smell like vinegar, or is it just really tart?

Comment: starsan no rinse

Comment: it tastes vinigary and wrong.

Comment: Any fruit flies buzzing around your airlocks?

Comment: hmm not that I noticed, But I wasn't looking for it.

Comment: @FrancisYaconiello: The sugar dissolved into 2 cups water: was the water boiled/sterilized first? Also, why only a half-packet of yeast?

Comment: I did boil the water, and a half packet b/c I normally use a full packet on 5 gallon batches of beer and I was making a 1 gallon batch of cider

Comment: There is lots of information missing here. What your process is, sanitization, not to mention time you waited for each recipe. Did you bottle or carbonate them at all, or are you drinking it straight from the jug?

Comment: @Graham could you explain me the issue with fruit flies?

Comment: Fruit flies are notorious harbingers of 'acetobacter', which is basically bacteria that convert alcohol into acids. Tobias' answer explains it nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the cider is really turning into vinegar, than you've got a bacterial infection, probably [acetobacter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetic_acid_bacteria). This bacteria will metabolize alcohol into acetic acid.  Acetobacter is present in small quantities in apple juice. It's also carried by fruit flies.

There are three things you can do to fix this.

1. Observe proper sanitation technique. Anything the contacts the juice or the finished cider should be free of contaminants like bacteria, mould, or wild yeast. Palmer's *How to Brew* has a good [section](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter2-2.html) on sanitation.
2. Dose the juice with potassium metabisulfite 24 hours before pitching the yeast. This shouldn't be necessary with pasteurized juice, and a lot of cider makers (myself included) skip this step even with raw juice.  The k-meta will reduce activity from bacteria and wild yeasts, given the brewer's yeast a head-start at becoming the dominant micro-organism.
3. And it goes without saying (but I'll say it anyway) -- use an airlock during fermentation to prevent any airborne contagions (including flies) from getting at the juice.

Comment: Nice answer. Just want to underline that acetobacter is pretty much everywhere, including house dust.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I'll try once more and see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

ALL IS NOT LOST!!!!

I had a similar problem with a distinctly vinegar flavour to my apple cider having left it maybe two days too long in the fermenter.

With Scottish blood flowing through my Kiwi veins, I couldn't stand the thought of it going to waste, so I boiled 2/3rds of the cider-vinegar to 70 degrees C (killing just enough yeast to sufficiently ferment the added sugar from the apple juice to the point of carbonation and no further), then added 9 litres of preservative-free apple juice.

I prayed and I trusted, and even only two weeks later have enjoyed the finest cider I've made to date (further enhanced by watching the All Blacks beat our arch-rivals, the Wallabies, in Yokohama as I did it)!

Comment: "killing just enough yeast to sufficiently ferment the added sugar from the apple juice to the point of carbonation and no further" do you mean leaving not killing?